how to get feature importance on unseen test data
I trained a random forest classifier with a set of features and saved the model. (the features were selected based on their correlations with the response variable. Only those features with significant correlations were chosen). I used the feature_importances_ function of sklearn to get the features important for making the predictions for the trained model on the test set.
Now, I want to use the saved classifier to get prediction on a new test set (with the same features as those of the trained model as input). How do I know what features were important contributing factors to the predictions for the new test set? Should I still use feature_importances_ for this?

You could look at different model explainability methods such as SHAP or LIME.

feature_importances_ can be differently described for any different model you are using. It is a measure of showing which feature is more crucial in predicting the target variable in general, without taking into consideration train or test data.
